# Trying to extract the Desired Strings from Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Extract the String from the Data available in the Cell `"A2"` and `"A5"`.

From Cell `"A2"` i.e. `Young, Yamen (09/21/1960 M)`

From Cell `"A5"` i.e.

```
Insurance: CHIP(U4024563201)   Location:  (Far Rockaway)   Type: Radiology - Results Follow-up
```

[image]

I want to extract these below details from above data

```
Young, Yamen in B2
9/21/1960 in C2 
CHIP in D2  
U4024563201 in E2
```

[image]

But when i run the code the details appear like this:
[image]

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim val As String
Dim val2 As String
Set ws = Sheet1

val = ws.Range("A2")
val2 = ws.Range("A5")
On Error Resume Next

ws.Range("B2") = Split(val, "(")(0)
ws.Range("C2") = Right(val, Len(val) - (InStrRev(val, "(")))
ws.Range("D2") = Left(val2, Len(val2) - (InStrRev(val2, ":")))
ws.Range("E2") = Left(val2, Len(val2) - (InStrRev(val2, ")")))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So without testing your code, it looks like it should work. You don't mention what the problem actually is. That said. you may want to remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code as it only hides potential problems.

Comment: Problem is that my code is not extracting the Exact information as available in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaPDI.png @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67640424/edit) to expand on what is not working. What happens  if you remove `On Error Resume Next` as suggested above

Comment: I edited the question nothing happen with or without `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: I assume `ws` is assigned to the correct sheet? Try using `Set ws = ActiveSheet`. If that doesn't help, try adding `value` after each range (ex.: `ws.Range("B2").value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having some problems with the `Left` and `Right` functions?
You can use them in combination to pick out a section, or use the `Mid` Function.
I'm not sure how consistent your formatting is, but here is an example that should work on the current example:

```
ws.Range("B2") = Split(val, "(")(0)
ws.Range("C2") = Left(Right(val, Len(val) - (InStrRev(val, "("))), 10)
ws.Range("D2") = Mid(val2, InStr(val2, ":") + 2, InStr(val2, "(") - InStr(val2, ":") - 2)
ws.Range("E2") = Mid(val2, InStr(val2, "(") + 1, InStr(val2, ")") - InStr(val2, "(") - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @Christofer Weber this is working awesome. Can you please have a look on the further process of this code here [Ahead work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638379/extracting-the-required-strings-from-the-data)
 i would really appreciated your help.